# Django F() and ExpressionWrapper

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

I am trying to avoid DB hits on my views.py. If I used the F() and ExpressionWrapper, Am I doing a query on the database. I am trying to optimize my code and kind of confused when I read the documentation. I also included the Models.py for reference. I am doing an optimization on the web application that I am working.

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db.models import F, Q, Count, Sum, ExpressionWrapper, IntegerField
from .models import Student, Subject, Enrollment


def home(request):
    student = Student.objects.all()
    subject = Subject.objects.all()
    sem_score = Enrollment.objects.all().update(sem_score=ExpressionWrapper((F("prelim_score") + F("midterm_score") + F("final_score"))/3, output_field=IntegerField()))
    enrollment = Enrollment.objects.all()
    num_student = Enrollment.objects.all().count()
    context = {"student":student, "subject":subject, "enrollment":enrollment, "num_student":num_student}
    return render(request, 'core/home.html', context)
```

Models.py

```
class Professor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    course = models.ManyToManyField(Course)
    enroll = models.ManyToManyField(Student, through='Enrollment')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    
    
class Enrollment(models.Model):
    GRADE_STATUS = (
        ("A","A"),
        ("B", "B"),
        ("C", "C"),
    )
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    professor = models.ForeignKey(Professor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    prelim_score = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    midterm_score = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True,  default=0)
    final_score = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True,  default=0)
    sem_score = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True,  default=0)
    sem_status = models.CharField(choices=GRADE_STATUS , max_length=50, null=True, blank=True,  default=0)
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.student} enrolled in {self.subject}"
```

Comment: Please show your models

Comment: Just updated my post.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is not working or what your question is?

Comment: Everything is working. I am trying to figure out if those clauses will have a DB hit every time I will run the program.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I used the F() and ExpressionWrapper, Am I doing a query on the database

```py
sem_score = Enrollment.objects.all().update(
    sem_score=ExpressionWrapper(
        (F("prelim_score") + F("midterm_score") + F("final_score")) / 3,
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    )
)
```

Some important notes to consider with the above:

1. Querysets are lazy, meaning they don't do anything until they are *evaluated*.
2. `F()` expressions (and `ExpressionWrapper`) are for defining expressions that are executed **by the database**, rather than in-memory by Python. Django creates an expression as part of its query that is sent to the database; it is never evaluated by or even returned to Django.
3. When you call `.update` on the queryset returned from `.all()`, it will immediately evaluate the queryset and perform the update. That's when the query (along with your expressions) are sent to the DB and the DB evaluates the expression on the database server.

So, to answer your question directly: no, calling `F()` or `ExpressionWrapper()`, alone, does not query the database. Once django *does* talk to the database, it sends along your expression to be evaluated by the DB. The expression evaluation takes place strictly on the database, not in Python.

Also, because your model fields referenced in the `F()` expressions are all of the same type, you do not need the `ExpressionWrapper`:

```py
sem_score = Enrollment.objects.all().update(
    sem_score=(F("prelim_score") + F("midterm_score") + F("final_score")) / 3
)
```

Comment: Your explanation is extremely helpful. Thank you for this one.